# How can I put an XML mocked payload into a POST request payload sended by a WSO2 ESB send mediator?

Tags: middleware, wso2, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2 ESB** and at this time I have to achive this first simple task but I really don't know from where start.

I have to perform an **HTTP POST request** towards an external web service. This request should contains a mocked **XML** document as payload (at this time the XML have to be merely mocked so I think that I have to "write" it somewhere or something like this).

So starting by this minimalistic official tutorial:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message

I have done the following operation:

1) I have created a new **ESB Solution Project**.

2) On the "main" project named **SampleServices** (at this time I am using the same name of the tutorial) I have registered the **endpoint** to my external web service (**New -> Endpoint**).

3) Then on this project I have add a new **RESP API** (**New -> REST API**). Differently from the tutorial I have enable **POST** request instead of **GET** into the **API Resource properties** because I need to send a **POST** request containing a payload instead the tutorial **GET** request. This is my settings:

[image]

4) Then, as done in the tutorial, I have setted the **send mediator** and on this mediator I have setted the **defined endpoint** pointing at my external web service that have to handle the **POST** request and retrieve its payload.

Ok, now my problem is: how can I put a mocked XML document into the body of my **POST** request sended by my *send mediator**?

Reading this second tutorial:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Routing+Requests+Based+on+Message+Content

I know that I can pass the request payload from outside, for example in this second tutorial perform this **CURL** call that starts the **ESB** "process":

```
curl -v -X POST --data @request.json http://localhost:8280/healthcare/categories/surgery/reserve --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

This do a call that pass a **JSON** as payload. In the previous example works fine but it is not good for me.

I have to mock the **XML** document payload inside my **ESB** API flow and not take from an external request performed by CURL because in a second implementationstep it will not be mocked but il will come from a previous step in the chain.

So I need a flow like this:

[image]

When my **API** is called it perform a **POST** request that send a mocked **XML payload**. Maybe it is have to be putted into the **send mediator** but I don't know...

How can I put this XML in the payload of the requeste sended by the **send mediator**? Where have I to define\write it?

Comment: You can use PayloadFactory mediator.

Comment: Andrea, it´s better to post your API or proxy xml...as Ernesto told you, try to put a payloadfactory before the send mediator with the xml you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/services/users" name="ListUsersAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="GET" protocol="http" url-mapping="/*">
    <inSequence>
      <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{ "persons":[{ "person": { "Id":"1", "givenName":"ajith", "lastName":"vitharana", "age":"25", "contactInfos":[ { "InfoId":"1", "department":"1", "contactType":"email", "value":"ajith@abc.org" }, { "InfoId":"2", "department":"1", "contactType":"mobile",
          "value":"111111111" }, { "InfoId":"3", "department":"1", "contactType":"home", "value":"Magic Dr,USA" } ] }}, {"person":{ "Id":"2", "givenName":"shammi", "lastName":"jagasingha", "age":"30", "contactInfos":[ { "InfoId":"1", "department":"1", "contactType":"email",
          "value":"shammi@abc.org" }, { "InfoId":"2", "department":"1", "contactType":"mobile", "value":"2222222222" }, { "InfoId":"3", "department":"1", "contactType":"home", "value":"Magic Dr,USA" } ] } }] }</format>
        <args/>
      </payloadFactory>
      <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
      <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
      <respond/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Hi, now I will try...I am very new in WSO2 ESB and I have some doubts about what have I to do with this sample. Where have I to put this XML code? I have created a new "ESB Solution Project". Then? What have I to do with this XML configuration?

Comment: So it seems to me that this is something like the api configuration file, is it?

Comment: Ok, I have imported it into an ESB API, now my doubt is: in this case the flow end with a "respond mediator" that I think returns to the caller the JSON...I have not to return to the caller but I have to send it to an external web service and not to return it to the caller. Have I to use a "send mediator" setting a "defined endpoint"? Have I to specify some particular settings for this mediator?

Comment: Another doubt is: why after the "PayLoadFactory" mediator (that seems to me is used to create the JSON payload) there are 2 "Property" mediators? What these 2 mediators does?

Comment: If you want to send the request to an external endpoint you can use: 1. the send mediator if you want that the response go to the outsequence, 2. the call mediator if you want that the response return to the insequence...the XML I use you can put inside [ESB_HOME]\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\api\ListUsersAPI.xml or create a new API using the DevStudio an replace it content with that xml.

Comment: Property = messageType: Message formatter is selected based on this property. This property should have the content type, such as text/xml, application/xml, or application/json.

Property = NO_ENTITY_BODY: This property should be removed if a user want to generate a response from the ESB to a request without an entity body, for example, GET request.